# Javascript (jQuery) effect waits for images to load

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this page that has some basic custom tabs:

http://demo.unlockedmanagement.com/users/view/2

***NOTE it will ask for a login, just use admin/password and then go to that url.**

Loading this page normally (except for the first time) and everything looks fine.  If I do a hard refresh of this page, the tabs/tabbed content appears as if the javascript has not yet been applied and the javascript only seem to be applied after the images are loaded.  The thing is that my javascript to apply the tabs looks like this (you can look at /javascript/base.js to see the whole thing):

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    //some code ...

    //tabbed data
    if($('.tabbed-data').length > 0)
    {
        $('.tabbed-data').tabs();
    }

    //some more code ...
});
```

I thought that using $(document).ready() will not wait for all the images to load so why am I seeing the delay in the javascript we doing a hard refresh?

Comment: The `$(document).ready()` will wait until the DOM has loaded fully and then execute the javascript.

Comment: If your code depends on loaded resources (e.g. images) use `$(window).on('load', function () {});`

Comment: @Yoshi, I dont think this is what he means. I think what he is trying to say is why is the page waiting for the images to load before executing the javascript? It is most likely a script loading issue

Comment: @BenCarey Ah I see, misread the question then, sorry :)

Comment: @Yoshi, Not probs. I did too, the first time! :-) See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script you are using is correct, `$(document).ready()` only waits until the DOM has loaded. It does not wait for the images to load. Therefore the problem is most likely to do with where you are loading the scripts.

In your code, you have placed the `<script>` tags at the base of the code. Why is that? This is most likely the issue as the browser will work its way down the page loading the assets in the order they appear.

Place you `<script>` tags in the `<head>` part of the page to load them before the images.

**The best way to test if this is the issue, is simply placing this in your header and see if it fires before the images load:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    //some code ...

    //tabbed data
    if($('.tabbed-data').length > 0)
    {
        $('.tabbed-data').tabs();
    }

    //some more code ...
});
</script>
```

Comment: Well it does look like move the javascrt to the head does fix that problem.  The reason I had the javascript file at the end of the page is that years ago I was told that it is better to have the javascript at the end of the page so that page seems like it is loading faster however it seems that might not always be a god idea as pointed out by this case.

Comment: @ryanzec I always place my javascript at the top of the page to ensure it is loaded before the content. I then place a loading icon on the page which is hidden once the content is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting your script tags in the header - I am wondering if your browser is still downloading images before it is downloading the scripts, so then .ready() is called way after the dom is ready.